# JWS stack overflow error

Tags: java, java-web-start

I like to use Java Web Start to put up a demo of my Java game to the web so that user can view and interact with the game characters and so on.

I exported the project to a jar file using Eclipse export runnable jar feature. I was then able to run it with `java -jar` successfully. I set up a `test.jnlp` file as below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="/home/bili/JWSdeploytest/" href="test.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <vendor>binman</vendor>
    <description>Test</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <jar href="LoadbonesFOrmat.jar" main="true"/>
    <extension name="Demo" href="test.jnlp" />
  </resources>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <application-desc />
</jnlp>
```

I tried to test it locally on my machine with debug turning on that I read from other post on here:

```
set JAVAWS_TRACE_NATIVE=1
set JAVAWS_VM_ARGS="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket, address=8989,server=y,suspend=n"
```

But when I run `javaws test.jnlp` I got `StackOverflowError`.  Below is output:

```
bili@bili-SFF:~/JWSdeploytest$ javaws -J test.jnlp 
Exception in thread "Demo" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.<init>(LinkedHashMap.java:362)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.<init>(LinkedHashMap.java:362)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$KeyIterator.<init>(LinkedHashMap.java:400)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$KeyIterator.<init>(LinkedHashMap.java:400)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.newKeyIterator(LinkedHashMap.java:413)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeySet.iterator(HashMap.java:891)
    at java.io.ExpiringCache.cleanup(ExpiringCache.java:117)
    at java.io.ExpiringCache.get(ExpiringCache.java:74)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.canonicalize(UnixFileSystem.java:152)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:576)
    at sun.security.provider.PolicyFile.canonPath(PolicyFile.java:1872)
    at java.io.FilePermission$1.run(FilePermission.java:203)
    at java.io.FilePermission$1.run(FilePermission.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.FilePermission.init(FilePermission.java:200)
    at java.io.FilePermission.<init>(FilePermission.java:266)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.config.DeploymentConfiguration.getProperty(DeploymentConfiguration.java:269)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.SecurityDesc.getCustomTrustedPolicy(SecurityDesc.java:172)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.SecurityDesc.<init>(SecurityDesc.java:159)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Parser.getSecurity(Parser.java:553)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile.parse(JNLPFile.java:594)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile.<init>(JNLPFile.java:178)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile.<init>(JNLPFile.java:211)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:351)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.initializeExtensions(JNLPClassLoader.java:370)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.<init>(JNLPClassLoader.java:174)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:295)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:351)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.initializeExtensions(JNLPClassLoader.java:370)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.<init>(JNLPClassLoader.java:174)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:295)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:351)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.initializeExtensions(JNLPClassLoader.java:370)
```

The three line 295:351:370 are repeated dozen more time.
It looks to me from the output as if there is some restricted access going on. I checked and verified that the Jar file, jnlp are allowed to be executed/read.

I start to wonder if I need a web server to test it out. However few things that cast doubt in my mind as I never work with JWS before:

1. Something is wrong with the jar file (I didn't export it correctly)
2. The `test.jnlp` is not configured correctly

Any pointers as to how can I solve this JWS business?

Edit: I have removed the extention element and it throws another Exception:

```
    bili@bili-SFF:~/JWSdeploytest$ javaws test.jnlp 
net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Launch Error: Could not launch JNLP file.
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:596)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:887)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: file:/home/bili/JWSdeploytest/LoadbonesFOrmat.jar is not a cacheable resource
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.CacheUtil.getCacheFile(CacheUtil.java:297)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:561)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: file:/home/bili/JWSdeploytest/LoadbonesFOrmat.jar is not a cacheable resource
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.CacheUtil.getCacheFile(CacheUtil.java:297)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:561)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:887)
```

This one seems more intuitive and I'm positive this timethat I haven't packed the Jar file correctly. Going to try it again later.
Here is the output from JaNeLA:

```
content type application/xml does not equal expected type of application/x-java-jnlp-file
XML encoding not known, but declared as utf-8
Codebase '/home/bili/JWSdeploytest/' is a malformed URL!  Defaulting to file:/home/bili/JWSdeploytest/test.jnlp
Codebase '/home/bili/JWSdeploytest/' is a malformed URL!  Defaulting to file:/home/bili/JWSdeploytest/test.jnlp
Codebase '/home/bili/JWSdeploytest/' is a malformed URL!  Defaulting to file:/home/bili/JWSdeploytest/test.jnlp
Codebase '/home/bili/JWSdeploytest/' is a malformed URL!  Defaulting to file:/home/bili/JWSdeploytest/test.jnlp
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'LoadbonesFOrmat.jar'.
The resource download at LoadbonesFOrmat.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for LoadbonesFOrmat.jar unless the download 'part' is specified.
```

I've moved the security element above resource element to get rid of the cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: according to JaNeLa's help file on the website. In console, it says document is valid but the data might still be wrong!

Comment: You have added the `applet` tag to the question but the JNLP indicates this is an application (JWS can launch either).  Is it an applet, or not?

Comment: it's not an applet sorry! It was really early and I was just trying to finish the question.

Comment: Thanks for confirming (and the good sense to edit the tags).  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of suspicious aspects to the JNLP file.  Most *especially* that it is `test.jnlp` but also claims to load an extension of the same name!  That might be what is causing the stack overflow.

Validate the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).  It will identify some other problems as well.  As the author of JaNeLA, I'll be interested to hear if it also throws a `StackOverflowError`, since it tries to validate the main JNLP *as well as any extension*. I suspect it will go into an infinite loop (please report back).

I am guessing there is only the one Jar.  If that is the case, remove the entire `extension` element.

BTW - is the Jar really called `LoadbonesFOrmat.jar`?  That is very odd use of upper case letters, I would have called it `LoadbonesFormat.jar` or `LoadBonesFormat.jar` (i.e. no upper case `O`).

Comment: Thanks. I will try it later when I get back home and report back. And yes, it is indeed called LoadbonesFOrmat.jar, but it should have been LoadbonesFormat.jar. I can't remember exactly how that happened...

Comment: Cool.  JaNeLA should have a lot to say about the JNLP file, in that case (about comment 1).

Comment: ops, forgot to mark your answer as correct! I have a small question though, I dont need a web server to test the jnlp file,yes?

Comment: No, it should not need a server for testing, each of the JWS based projects offered [here](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html) are designed to be tested from the local file-system (built/launched using Ant).

Comment: Thank you. Will check out your link.